# Why existence of bijective function between two sets means that they have the same number of elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is wrong with the following logic - let's say there exists $f:A\rightarrow B$ that is bijective, and $g:A\rightarrow B$ that is injective but not bijective. Then in $g$ for every member of $A$ there is a corresponding value of $B$ but there are some values of $B$ that haven't got a pair with any element of $A$. So doesn't  that mean that $B$ is "bigger" than $A$? ($|A|<|B|$)

But then when analyzing $f$ we see that $|A|=|B|$. So why is one conclusion wrong and the other one right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel

Comment: If $g : A \rightarrow B$ is injective but not bijective, that doesn't prove $|A| < |B|$. Consider e.g. the function $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by $g(n)=n+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help plugging in some known sets. For example take $A=B=\mathbb N$ and
$$ f(n)=n \qquad g(n)=n+1 $$
Then, if your reasoning works:

> In $g$ for every member of $\mathbb N$ there is a corresponding <s>value</s>member of $\mathbb N$ but there are some <s>values</s>members of $\mathbb N$ that <s>haven't got a pair with</s> are not the image (under $g$) of any elemebt of $\mathbb N$. So doesn't that mean that $\mathbb N$ is bigger than $\mathbb N$?

You just have to come to terms with the fact that for an infinite set there can be a injective-but-not-surjective map from the set *to itself* -- in particular the existence of an injective-but-not-surjective map doesn't necessarily mean that the sets are even *different*.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean that $B$ "is bigger than $A$". It means that $A$ could be at most "the size of $B$". I.e.

$|A|\le |B|$ is equivalent to: there exists an injection from $A$ to $B$ with equality holding if and only if there exists a *bijection* from $A$ to $B$. For example, take the map from the Naturals to the evens, defined by:
$$
f(n) = 2n
$$
This maps the natural numbers to a subset of itself! We don't conclude that the evens "are bigger than the naturals!" They are in fact, equal in cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

This "paradox" is precisely the definition of infiniteness: a set $S$ is infinite if there exists a non bijective injection $f:S\to S$.

You could say, in an intuitive approach, that if you remove some elements from an infinite set, the set will be still infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a bijection means there is a way of making a "mirror" image of one set as the other; that is, we have a tool to transform one set into another via the bijection, without leaving any elements out of the picture. As long as we know there is at least one way we can do that, we know the two sets are equal in size. As a counter example to what you have proposed, consider $g: \Bbb{R}^+ \to \Bbb{R}$ where $g(x) = \ln(x)$. Clearly $g$ is an injective function but it is absolutely incorrect to conclude that $|\Bbb{R}^+| <  |\Bbb{R}|$.

Answer (score 0):

If the sets are infinite there could be a lot of different injections, some of which are bijective and other not. Suppose the map $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, defined this way $$f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2, & \mbox{if } n\mbox{ is even} \\ -\frac{n+1}{2}, & \mbox{if } n\mbox{ is odd} \end{cases}$$Then $f$ is bijective, so $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Z}|$, but if you get the identity as your injective function you might think that $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{Z}|$, which is obviously wrong. This is the case only when you can prove that there doesn't exist bijection.